# Создание виртуального монитора для Виртуальной Машины

Tags: rdp, vnc, connection

коллеги.

Перерыл весь интернет на обоих языках, но ничего не нашел по следующей теме:

Как сделать так, чтобы у Виртуальной Машины всегда был активный Виртуальный Монитор?

Объясняя ситуацию - Я RPA разработчик в одном из банков, и для того чтобы некоторые мои роботы могли работать с селекторами, которые имитируют клики на кнопках ПО, сайтов или считывают текст со скана - им нужен монитор. Если я подключаюсь к Виртуальной Машине (по РДП), то я открываю сессию и создаю этот монитор, но я не могу быть постоянно подключен к ВМ и по ряду причин - вариант с подключением через RDP - отпадает, так как на ВМ постоянно заходят админы и другие разработчики - и монитор созданный РДП подключением - гаснет, после их выхода с ВМ.

Уже с ДИБом и Сис. Админами обсуждали темы:
VNC
Подключения к консоли ВМ (для подключения через Google Chrome)
MSC
RDP

И все вышеперечисленное - либо было заблокировано ДИБом, либо не подходит в использовании, и поэтому - Как дать Виртуальной Машине виртуальный монитор, который бы она активировала каждый раз, как человек отключается от RDP?

Или же просто - киньте сюда свои практики или идеи, которые использовали.

Спасибо!

Comment: ос какая? по какому приложению кликаете?

Comment: Windows 10, по любым пиложениям, будь то Google Chrome или Adobe PDF reader

Comment: сделай виртуальную машину на hyperv

Comment: Прошел целый год, а ответа так и нет. Или вы уже решили как-то эту задачу?!